# "dotnet restore" command fails with Restore failed Response is not a valid NuGet v2 service response

Tags: .net, cross-platform, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to instal .NET core on Ubuntu 14.04 following the steps shown in this link http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/
But i cannot pass the 4th step:
"dotnet restore", it displays the following error in terminal:

```
Error: FindPackagesById: System.Console
  Response from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.jsonFindPackagesById()?id='System.Console' is not a valid NuGet v2 service response.
```

and other warnings like this:

```
Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Console
  Response from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.jsonFindPackagesById()?id='System.Console' is not a valid NuGet v2 service response.
```

I don't understand the reason of this failure. all previous steps worked normally. help me please! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i have fixed this by executing the following commands:

```
$ dnu clear-http-cache
```

And after executing:

```
$ dnu list
```

And then i found out that i have unresloved references, terminal showed this:

```
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Mono-x64-1.0.0-rc1-16231

Listing dependencies for devnet (/home/red/Desktop/devnet/project.json)

[Target framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (dnxcore50)]

Unresolved references:
* Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime 1.0.1-beta - Unresolved
* System.Console 4.0.0-beta - Unresolved
* System.IO 4.0.11-beta - Unresolved
* System.Runtime 4.0.21-beta - Unresolved
```

After i run this command:

```
    $ dnu install Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime 1.0.1-beta Microsoft .NET Development Utility Mono-x64-1.0.0-rc1-16231
```

after this i have got a successful restore

```
Restore complete, 6771ms elapsed
```

Note: if you have access permession problem when executing `$ dnu install`
you have to change permission of `/.dnu` directory with chmod

:)